# Time Capsule disappears from Finder

Tags: macos, finder, time-capsule

My time capsule is disappearing from my Finder list (left side) occasionally.. it is very odd.  I have my iMac plugged in to it via Ethernet cable.  How do I force my iMac to connect to it when it misbehaves like this?

Answer (score 1):

If it's connected via Ethernet the most likely cause is the drive has fallen asleep and your system has lost its connection with the drive. The remedy: open the drive about once every two or three hours to keep it awake.